# geom_bar multiple criteria to sort and color

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar, stackedbarseries

I have a data.table that Im plotting with geom_bar.
The data.table has multiple pieces of information (aa, codon, pos) by which the counts (value/contig) can be grouped. For now, Im plotting contig (y) at each pos (x) by aa_codon.
rn  aa codon pos variable       value      contig
1: ASP_GAT_-17 ASP   GAT -17      PC3  0.33962840  0.33962840
2: ASP_GAC_-17 ASP   GAC -17      PC3  0.29253629  0.29253629
3: SER_TCT_-17 SER   TCT -17      PC3  0.27009135  0.27009135

I managed to sort x by the position and the stacked bar by using fill according to which codon-pos is higher. However, each aa_codon_pos appears in one color and I would like that the color was by aa (keeping the same order). Every attempt to fill them by aa results in incorrect order of the stacked bar (since it summarizes all the codon_pos for that aa). Is there any way to sort and color the stacked bars independently?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWSPl.png)

Comment: Can you make this problem reproducible? I'm also confused by how the jargon relates to the plot, even though I work in mol bio too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.